# How to turn curve into mesh?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, geometry

I created a "path" curve and add geometry using "Bevel object". How to turn this object into a simple mesh?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it!

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text

[image]